# Auto-generated key in ER/Studio

Tags: database

If anybody knows please tell how to declare a key as auto-generated in ER/Studio 8.0.
Its urgent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done. Check the identity option, providing the seed and increment, while defining a key.